# Mongoose not creating document on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am using Next.js and MongoDB (mongoose) to make an education portal website. The school admin can add important notices from their dashboard and the student can view them from theirs. Most mongoose operations have to be done in an API that next.js provides them self so my code to create the document on MongoDB is located in /API/ directory. Code:

```js
/**
 * @param {import("next").NextApiRequest} req
 * @param {import("next").NextApiResponse} res
 */

import circulars from '../../../model/hw'

export default async function stuffss(req, res) {
    try{
        const {number, text} = req.body
        console.log("Connecting to mongo")
        mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://usernameherer:passowordhere@cluster0.clusteridhere.mongodb.net/stuff?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
        console.log("Connected to mongo")
    
        console.log("Creating document")
        const createdCircular = await circulars.create(req.body)
        
        console.log("Created document")
        res.json({ createdCircular })
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.json({ error })
    }
}
```

The circulars schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')



const circularsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    number: {
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        type: Number
    },
    text: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    }
})

const circulars = mongoose.models.circularss || mongoose.model("circularss", circularsSchema)

export default circulars
```

Sending a post request using insomnia gives the following result:

```json
{
    "createdCircular": {
        "number": 15463,
        "text": "loreum ipsum",
        "_id": "63cb86421ca543a731cb39c3",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

but when I go and look for it on the MongoDB website it doesn't have any results.
I believe it may be because of how I am connecting or that I am not sending it properly to a collection.

This is the structure of my database:
[image: Stuff -> circulars]

---

Is there a way to connect to the 'stuff' database and 'circulars' collection?

Comment: Do you actually connect to mongodb? Is see a `console.log("Connecting to mongo")`, but miss the actual function to do so.

Comment: @ChristianUnnerstall edited my question to be connected to the db from the backend. Still the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this issue. In my schema I had put the same `circulars` which created created a new collection for it, I also had to remove await from  `mongoose.connect`. This combined fixed the issue for me. You should also make sure that  `mongoose.models.name` is the same as the `mongoose.model("name", schema)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the database needs to be specified in connection string.

E.g.

```
...clusteridhere.mongodb.net/stuff?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Ref: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: Still no change.

Comment: On the MongoDB end have you checked if your data was created in some other default database and/or collection. I see in your schema `circularss` with 2 s.

Comment: Yes, I did check. I was not created anywhere.